# Viability of bladeless wind power generation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, wind-power, power-generation

I have recently thought of two designs for bladeless wind power generation;[image]
And[image]

They both essentially ionizes the incoming wind which then passes through a coil, the flow of charged wind particles would induce an electric current in the coil.

A few questions regarding these designs;

Are either of these designs even capable of generating electricity?

If not, then what alterations can be made for either of them to be functional?

If they are capable of generating electricity then what would be a theoretical estimate for their efficiency?

Comment: So, what have you tested?

Comment: I haven't actually built it yet, I want to be sure that it will produce a reasonable amount of power before I invest anything in actually building it.

Comment: Engineers often build scale models...

Comment: Your ions flowing through the coil will form a DC current. How do you propose that would induce a current in the coil? What is the advantage of ionising the air compared with just running the red wire through the funnel in Image 2?

Comment: Fast moving charged particles have a magnetic field, a moving magnetic field would induce a current in the coil, higher wind speed would mean higher rate of changing magnetic field hence more power could be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

Your scheme already exists in the form of something called a *magnetohydrodynamic (MHD) generator*. To make it work requires a huge ion flux traveling at high speed, which ordinary air and wind cannot furnish.